# Applied Subdivision Modifier, but subdivided plane only appears in Wireframe view?

Tags: subdivision-surface

I've applied the 'Subdivision Surface' modifier to my plane, but the subdivisions only appear when I'm in Wireframe View? I also cannot seem to select individual faces in Edit mode either.

I've toggled with various buttons, including *Optimal Display*, *On Cage*, *GPU Subdivision* in *Preferences*, but to no luck unfortunately.

[image]

Comment: I was just writing an answer when you posted yours, well I gave it anyway because there is an additional mode to show the wireframe. But your question was unclear, you did not say you wanted to see the wireframe in _Object Mode_ explicitly (because "Wireframe View" could be in _Edit Mode_ as well). What is confusing me in your screenshot though is that the plane should show the subdivisions there, since the modifier has the display options _Edit Mode_ and _On Cage_ enabled and _Optimal Display_ disabled... even if set to _Display As_ > _Bounds_ they should show up in _Edit Mode_.

Answer (score 8):

Of course you cannot select the subdivided faces as long as the modifier is not applied, because the modifier is procedural and creates only "virtual" geometry, it is not real and can be changed anytime by changing the subdivision levels for example. You have to be careful with the terminology here to avoid misunderstandings: your title and question say, you have "applied" a modifier on the plane while you actually just added a modifier to it. "Applying" a modifier in Blender means, creating real geometry from the modifier's settings and removing the modifier, thus making the changes to the mesh permanent and no longer changeable.

Seeing the wireframe in *Object Mode* can be achieved in two ways:

1. Per object by enabling *Wireframe* under *Object Properties* > *Viewport Display*.
2. For all objects by enabling *Wireframe* in the *Overlays* for the *3D Viewport* (the *Opacity* setting there effects the per object wireframe as well).

Note: If an object is set to *Display As* > *Bounds* in the *Viewport Display* options, it will only show the bounds and no wireframe, no matter where you enabled it (in *Object Mode*, but the mesh will be shown in *Edit Mode*).

Also an object with a *Subdivision Surface* modifier will not show the subdivided wireframe as long as *Optimal Display* is enabled in the modifier settings, no matter which method you choose.

[image: wireframe settings]

Answer (score 0):

I can only select/edit individual faces after applying the modifier to the mesh. If I want to view the subdivided grid outside *Edit Mode*, I need to go to *Viewport Display* on the bottom right, and check the *Wireframe* Box.