# Edges of the model are visible in Object Mode

Tags: objects, edit-mode, import, edges, wireframe

I'm not in *Edit Mode*, but the Edges of the model are visible. How can I hide them in *Object Mode*?

[image]

In Blender, I'm not in Edit Mode, but the edges of the model are visible.

Comment: I've explained the different ways to show the wireframe in my answer here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/297760/applied-subdivision-modifier-but-subdivided-plane-only-appears-in-wireframe-vie/297763#297763

Answer (score 6):

Untick the *Wireframe* checkbox in the [`Viewport Overlays`](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/display/overlays.html#geometry) menu:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

To add to Harry's answer, also maybe you've enabled the *Wireframe* option under *Object > Viewport Display*:

[image]

Comment: Oh I didn't know that existed as well +1

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie You could have known that, you edited an answer at this question [Applied Subdivision Modifier, but subdivided plane only appears in Wireframe view?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/297760/) where all methods listed in both your answers are already explained ;)

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann hahaha oh my.. I'm getting old and forgetful XD

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie Well, it's already been a month or so... that's about half an eternity ago :D