# Edit Mode Stuck in “X-Ray” View

Tags: materials, edit-mode, import, wireframe, collada

[image][image]

While in Edit Mode, the edges of my model inside and outside are visible simultaneously; this happened after importing a model I downloaded.

I'm not in X-Ray mode in Blender, but it seems like wireframe is showing through from the behind

Comment: Did nothing in the info provided for your [previous question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/300497/edges-of-the-model-are-visible-in-object-mode)   work? Can you share your blend file https://blend-exchange.com

Comment: maybe a Clipping issue? in the N panel pley with the values to see if it fixes the problem